# Просмотр установленных пакетов в Docker контейнерах

Tags: docker

Имеются поднятые Docker контейнеры, на которых работают приложения (nginx, apache и т.д.)

Как вывести список и версию установленных приложений на этих контейнерах?

Comment: В зависимости от базового образа, можно использовать утилиты dpkg, rpm и пр.

Answer (score 1):

Запустить контейнеры в интерактивном режиме и воспользоваться штатными командами пакетного менеджера(apt/dnf/apk etc, в зависимости от того какой дистрибутив является основой для построения контейнера.)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, оказалось в `docker inspect <Container ID> | grep VERSION`